# What is wrong with this <%= stylesheet_tag %>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

This is what I have:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "skeleton-v1.1", "flexslider-v1.8", "main-r7", "media-queries-r6", "sprites-r7", "theme-default-r6", font_path("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,400italic"), :media => "all" %>
```

I am trying to push to Heroku and this is the error I am getting:

```
Started GET "/" for XX.XXX.XX.XX at 2012-06-07 04:45:14 +0000
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "background:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " -webkit-linear..."
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:     17: 
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "skeleton-v1.1", "flexslider-v1.8", "main-r7", "media-queries-r6", "sprites-r7", "theme-default-r6", "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,400italic", :media => "all" %>
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon', :type => 'image/png' %>      
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-72x72.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '72x72' %>     
2012-06-07T04:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__609869981572297479_34051980'
```

I even tried taking out the `font_path` helper and just including the URL alone, but that didn't work.

Thoughts?

P.S. I am pushing to a Cedar stack - if that matters.

**Edit 1:**

Application.CSS

```
/*
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

**Edit 2:**

I found a few lines in my CSS that have `webkit-linear`...how do I make this work? I can comment them out in the short-term, but I need them working.

Thoughts?

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.09) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
```

Comment: Please paste application.css.

Comment: Please check a semicolon near '-webkit-linear' of application.css

Comment: Problem in one of your included .css. Search pattern '-webkit-linear' in files which you inclide in stylesheet_link_tag. Parser can't recognize this pattern.

Comment: Ok I found it, but what should I use instead? This is what I found ` background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.09) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to comment out this line in one of my stylesheets.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.09) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
```

I don't know what the real solution is, but this work-around seems to have worked for me.